# Get Table Data from op2 file using pyNastran

Tags: python, nastran

I am trying to read final separation distances from an op2 file. I can see the table name (OSPDS1) is included in `model.table_names`, where model is the return value from `read_op2(file_name, build_dataframe=True, debug=False)`.

I have read every page of pyNastran's documentation and cannot for the life of me figure out how to retrieve the data for a table. I know the name I'm looking for is OSPDS1 based on the op2_scalar source code (https://pynastran-git.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyNastran/op2/op2_interface/op2_scalar.html?highlight=separation#). I think one of `set_additional_generalized_tables_to_read()` or `set_additional_result_tables_to_read(tables)` is part of the answer. I've gotten each of them to run using the `_table_mapper` output, but then don't know what to do from there. Do I reread the op2 file somehow now that I've set this table to be read?

I can't really provide a minimum running example because I can't upload the op2 file. If absolutely necessary, I can create a new run of some simplified geometry.

Comment: Given the limited traffic in SO for the Nastran tag, and special focus of pyNastran, you may not get an answer. Have you asked the pyNastran developer (Steven Doyle or M4 Engineering)?

Comment: I have put in an issue on pyNastran for Steven. How is M4 Engineering connected here?

Comment: Apparently the data I'm looking to access is not currently supported by pyNastran. Here is the issue tracking that status: https://github.com/SteveDoyle2/pyNastran/issues/639

Comment: While Googling pyNastran, I found Steven's GitHub site, and his LinkedIn Profile (which shows he works at M4). The M4 site lists pyNastran at the bottom of the software page. See this [M4 Engineering - Software](https://www.m4-engineering.com/engineering-software/) Good luck.